# Linux how to record sound in RAM buffer and playback audio with custom delay

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, jack

I need to send audio from a radio to a secondary system using an embedded linux system.

The secondary system needs to set up a communication channel which takes a few seconds.

So if I don't want to lose the beginning of the audio, I need a way to record the sound and play it back with a custom delay (a few seconds maximum).

It should be possible to start `arecord` to record the audio in a file in a tmpfs filesystem, and, when a communication is incoming, start `aplay`.
But in this case the beginning is still lost because the signal to record is coming too late.

Is there a program on Linux which is recording sound continuously in a ring buffer in RAM and able to playback with a custom delay on demand ?

If not, what is the best library to code such a program on an embedded system ? alsa or something else ?

Comment: On Linux, every audio library eventually ends up using ALSA. However, you can use any other library if it's easier to use.

Comment: Is this question off-topic since it asks for a tool or library?

Comment: Alsa has support for LADSPA plugins, there should be one featuring a fixed delay.

Comment: Is it appropriate to code up a script to do the buffer and pipe stuff together like `in | buffer-me 5s | out`? Such a script would be fairly trivial to write, if perhaps in a naive way. Of course it would be more efficient to do it in the existing sink or source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple C program that will maintain a circular buffer between pipe in and out. Use like `in | buffer_program | out`. Error checking omitted. Robustness not guaranteed. Gives the general idea.

Test script (but actually since its circular buffer the data your piping in needs to be such that its coherent taking just any chunk in the stream. Or just make the buffer bigger than the data):

```
cat some.wav | ./circular_buffer 100000 | (sleep 1 && aplay)
```

**circular_buffer.c:**

```
 /**
 * This program simply maintains a circular buffer of a given size indefinitely.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h> /* C99 only */
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int c_read(int fd, char * buf, unsigned int size, unsigned int * head_in, unsigned int * tail_in);
int c_write(int fd, char * buf, unsigned int size, unsigned int * head_in, unsigned int * tail_in);
bool empty_buf(unsigned int head, unsigned int tail);
bool setblock(int fd, bool block);
#define FD_SET_SET(set, fd, max) FD_SET(fd, &set); max = ((fd > max) ? fd : max);
#define FD_SET_UNSET(set, fd, max) FD_CLR(fd, &set); max = ((fd == max) ? max - 1  : max);  //not ideal. Do while ISFDSET...

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char * buf;
  unsigned int buf_size = 0;
  unsigned int buf_head = 0;
  unsigned int buf_tail = 0;

  // Check args.
  if(argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <buffer size in bytes>\n", __FILE__);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &buf_size);
  buf_size = ( buf_size < 2 ) ? 2 : buf_size;

  // Note the usable buffer space is buf_size-1.
  fprintf(stderr, "Allocating %d\n", buf_size);
  buf = (char*)malloc(buf_size);

  bool done_reading = false;
  int maxfd = 0;
  fd_set r_set, w_set, r_tempset, w_tempset;
  setblock(STDIN_FILENO, false);
  setblock(STDOUT_FILENO, false);
  FD_ZERO(&r_set);
  FD_ZERO(&w_set);
  FD_ZERO(&r_tempset);
  FD_ZERO(&w_tempset);
  FD_SET_SET(r_tempset, STDIN_FILENO, maxfd);
  FD_SET_SET(w_tempset, STDOUT_FILENO, maxfd);
  r_set = r_tempset;
  while(true) {
    select((maxfd + 1), &r_set, &w_set, NULL, NULL);
    if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &r_set)) {
      int c = c_read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, buf_size, &buf_head, &buf_tail);
      if(c == -1) { // EOF, disable select on the input.
        fprintf(stderr, "No more bytes to read\n");
        done_reading = true;
        FD_ZERO(&r_set);
      }
    }
    if(!done_reading) {
      r_set = r_tempset;
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(STDOUT_FILENO, &w_set)) {
      c_write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, buf_size, &buf_head, &buf_tail);
    }
    if(!empty_buf(buf_head, buf_tail)) { // Enable select on write whenever there is bytes.
      w_set = w_tempset;
    }
    else {
      FD_ZERO(&w_set);
      if(done_reading) { // Finish.
        fprintf(stderr, "No more bytes to write\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  fflush(stderr);
  return 0;
}

bool empty_buf(unsigned int head, unsigned int tail) {
  return head == tail;
}

/**
 * Keep reading until we can read no more. Keep on pushing the tail forward as we overflow.
 * Expects fd to be non blocking.
 * @returns number of byte read, 0 on non stopping error, or -1 on error or EOF.
 */
int c_read(int fd, char * buf, unsigned int size, unsigned int * head_in, unsigned int * tail_in) {
  fprintf(stderr, "In c_read()\n");
  unsigned int head = *head_in;
  unsigned int tail = *tail_in;
  bool more_bytes = true;
  int n = 0;
  int c = 0;

  while(more_bytes) {
    bool in_front = tail > head;
    fprintf(stderr, "Read %d %d %d\n", size, head, tail);

    n = read(fd, buf+head, size - head);
    if(n == -1) {
      more_bytes = false;
      if(errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EINTR) { // Not EOF but the read would block.
        c = 0;
      }
      else {
        c = -1;
      }
    }
    else if(n == 0) { // EOF. No more bytes possible.
      more_bytes = false;
      c = -1;
    }
    else if(n != (size - head)) { // if not full read adjust pointers and break.
      more_bytes = false;
      c += n;
      head = (head+n)%size;
      if(in_front && (head >= tail || head == 0)) {
        tail = (head+1)%size;
      }
    }
    else {
      c = 0;
      head = 0;
      tail = (tail == 0) ? 1 : tail;
    }
  }
  *head_in = head;
  *tail_in = tail;
  return c;
}

/**
 * Try flush the buffer to fd. fd should be non blocking.
 */
int c_write(int fd, char * buf, unsigned int size, unsigned int * head_in, unsigned int * tail_in) {
  fprintf(stderr, "In c_write()\n");
  unsigned int head = *head_in;
  unsigned int tail = *tail_in;
  int n = 0;
  fprintf(stderr, "Write %d %d %d\n", size, head, tail);

  if(tail < head) {
    n = write(fd, buf+tail, head-tail);
    tail += n;
  }
  else if(head < tail) {
    n = write(fd, buf+tail, size-tail);
    if(n == size-tail) {
      n = write(fd, buf, head);
      tail = n;
    }
  }
  *head_in = head;
  *tail_in = tail;
  return n;
}

bool setblock(int fd, bool block)
{
  int flags;
  flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
  if (block)
      flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
  else
      flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
  fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to have a buffer to keep sound output until it is ready to be consumed a variant of this should work:

Start recording:

```
mkfifo /tmp/f
stdbuf -o256M arecord -i | cat > /tmp/f
```

Start playing, when yours output device is ready:

```
aplay /tmp/f
```

Tweak the output buffer size to fit your needs.

EDIT (given that playing can start anytime):

If you need to *continuously* record and start playing *anytime* you could split the output into smaller files using the `split` command and delete the old files in a helper process.

Something like:

```
# Garbage collector
( while sleep 1 ; do rm $(ls *.blb 2>/dev/null | sort | head -n-3 ) > /dev/null 2>&1 ; done ) &
# Actual recording
arecord -i | split -a 10 -u -b 24576 --additional-suffix '.blb'
```

And to play:

```
{ while true ; do for f in $(find . -name '*.blb' -size 24576c | sort) ; do cat $f ; rm $f ; done ; done } | aplay
```

This solution is quite dirty, but *might* work (preferably on tmpfs as you have already mentioned)...

Comment: I would like to record all the time with a circular buffer (can be only 240K for 60s of 8000Hz 8bit audio) and then when it should play, it would use dd to play from the correct position in the buffer. In your case stdbuf will block when the buffer is full.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. I will edit with another idea (which is not a _perfect solution_, but might be a _working solution_)...